# VoIP call notification using firebase cloud messaging in React Native in iOS when app is in background or kill state

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, voip

We are implementing VoIP pushes in our app (iOS) using FCM for displaying incoming call in iOS.

We have done following steps:

- added VoIP certificate in developer console.
- added the APN certificate in firebase console.
- use `contentAvailable: true` & set `priority: "high"` for cloud messages.
- Setting `apns-priority` as 10 OR `apns-push-type` as voip results in error: invalid arguments.

Comment: did you found solution bro